# Swift Make Effect of Animation Permanent

Tags: swift, animation

I have looked all around but I haven't been able to find an answer to this simple question. Is there a way to make the effect of a Swift CABasicAnimation animation permanent? (Meaning that when the animation is over, the view won't reset to the state it was in before the animation began.)

Comment: you should take a look at fillModes https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Fill_Modes

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make the effect of a Swift CABasicAnimation animation permanent

Absolutely. Just set the same property that you are animating, to the value that it will have when the animation is over. You can do this at the same time you create and add the animation. (You'll probably want to turn implicit animation *off* when you do this, so that you don't animate *this* change as well.)

Example from my own code (I'm animating the `transform` of a layer called `arrow` so that it rotates):

```
let startValue = arrow.transform
let endValue = CATransform3DRotate(
    startValue, CGFloat(M_PI)/4.0, 0, 0, 1)
// change the layer, without implicit animation
// THIS IS WHAT YOU ARE ASKING ABOUT
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
arrow.transform = endValue
// construct the explicit animation
let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"transform")
anim.duration = 0.8
anim.fromValue = NSValue(CATransform3D:startValue)
anim.toValue = NSValue(CATransform3D:endValue)
// ask for the explicit animation
arrow.addAnimation(anim, forKey:nil)
```

Comment: And for a full discussion of the principles behind that code, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_using_a_cabasicanimation